# Prevent/punish self-duplicates

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I've been trawling unanswered [jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsoup) questions for a while and have been disturbed to find several instances of users asking the same question multiple times.  In one case, the user asked the same question four days in a row.  The question text was not exactly the same -- the user's example changed and the fourth question replaced the example with "pleas help" -- but the questions are undeniably duplicates.

When I see self-duplicates, I flag all but one as the duplicate of the one with the best answers (if any), then downvote that one.  I've never seen a case that doesn't deserve a downvote on its merits even without the self-duplication; if the question was good, the user wouldn't need to re-ask it to get an answer.  (I'd downvote all the self-duplicates if serial downvoting was permitted.)

But I think we could educate these users in a better way, hopefully one that prevents the duplicate(s), encourages users to improve their existing question, and doesn't add to the close votes queue.  Failing that, perhaps a ban/throttle will train them to treat their questions as a valuable resource.

The obvious technical measure has been implemented: if a user tries to post a precisely-identical question, the question is rejected.  But such users are already ignoring the "these questions may already have an answer" and "similar questions" boxes showing the duplicate, so the filter only [force them to misspell a word](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161398/houston-we-have-a-porblem) (or maybe more, not sure how tight the filter is).  This doesn't help much.

I don't have any better ideas at this point, hence [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion).

Is there anything we can do about this behavior, either user education (that reposting is not an acceptable way to get eyeballs on your question) or punishment (with a question-ban or throttle)?  I'd much prefer education, but it's not clear how to reach those users.  I did see one user (the example above) with two sets of self-duplicate questions, and a ban/throttle may have prevented the second, but in general the kinds of users who post self-duplicates aren't invested enough in the site to ask more than one set.

Related: [this meta.se post from 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67817/262399), which just asked why anyone would do such a thing, without proposing to do anything about it.

Comment: If this question has no answers by tomorrow, I'll post it again.

Comment: FWIW: obvious technical measure is already implemented. Hence the variation you see. Also worth noting that this sort of behavior is a great way to get question-banned in a "nothing you do to your existing questions can possibly help you" sort of way.

Comment: @Shog9: Thanks for the heads-up.  I was too nervous to try it for myself in that "even root can't rm -rf /" kind of way.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Our configuration "manager" once scrapped the entire build server by running rm -rf, as root, from the root. =D

Comment: This is another spot where the "ask a question wizard" I've suggested would help -- get a good title, show them multiple answers, **then** let them post. I think lazy people would be a lot less likely to go through that several times.

Comment: @Chris That is also a great way to get people to downvote questions just because it is not what they are looking for. People will think that with enough downvotes it wont be suggested. Downvotes are always bad, so it would have to be removed before pissing off the legitimate users.

Comment: When this occurs would a comment and downvote not suffice?

Comment: @Shog9: The filter could be stronger. For example, we could calculate the edit distance of a user's last two posts and see if they are substantially similar.

Comment: @MattCoubrough If the folks doing this get at most one downvote and a comment on one question if caught, but a higher possibility of getting an answer, what incentive do they have to play nice?

Comment: People obviously took your comment seriously... nobody is willing to answer just so you post the *same question* again.

Comment: I see this a lot where the user posts *across multiple sites* in a short period or over a couple of days. First they post on Stack Overflow, then an *identical* post appears on dba.stackexchange.com, serverfault.com, etc shortly after. Very frustrating - we really need a way to quickly mark and close these, as they're a waste of mods time and it's annoying explaining to people over and over why they shouldn't do this.

Comment: It's tomorrow. Eagerly awaiting your repost.

Comment: It's today over here. Damn these timezones.

Comment: "I'd downvote all the self-duplicates if serial downvoting was permitted." -- it is not "serial downvoting" if there is a justifiable reason for downvoting, e.g. poor quality. Or do you think you'd get punished by downvoting low quality content?

Comment: @MrJack - "That is also a great way to get people to downvote questions just because it is not what they are looking for..." - is that anecdotal, or can you cite a usability study that affirms it? (I have a morbid curiosity at times and it seems like it has some interesting UI repercussions, so I'd like to read about the behavior).

Comment: @Shog9 (or any other mods): When we see people do this, should we do more than just flag as duplicate? Should we flag for moderator attention? Also, does the filter detect if users delete a question, and then post the same question again the next day?

Comment: @Reto Koradi: The filter does not do anything beyond what it currently does (namely, prevent straight-up copy-pastes). Yes, if a user is doing it, especially despite being told not to by other members, you should flag for moderator attention so we can speak to them to try and get them to stop.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: I'd be surprised if the serial-downvoting-reversal script cared about my reasons.  I suppose I could flag a moderator and ask them to reverse the reversal, but that puts them in the position of judging whether my votes were justified.  In these cases, they would be, but I'm not sure we should set a precedent that serial voting is subject to appeal.

Comment: @BoltClock: It was a _joke_, of course, intended in the same spirit as ["vote for this question or the kitten gets it"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/) (no kittens were actually threatened).  I didn't intend to put discussion on hold for 24 hours.  My future joking comments will carry a disclaimer.

Comment: @Jeffrey Re-read BoltClock's comment and consider whether an active mod would *really* encourage users to re-post questions.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I don't know how exactly the serial-dv script works, but I believe that if the given post is already deemed as low quality (negative score/closed) and/or if the user has a high rate of low quality posts, the downvotes would have very little weight to trigger the serial-dv script (or so I believe, at least). Serial-downvoting is casting an unreasonable amount of unjustifiable downvotes into a given user's posts. Judging posts appropriately and casting votes will never be punished.

Comment: 71 upvotes for the question but 165 upvotes for the joke posted as comment... lol

Comment: @jww All data dealing with that has to be anecdotal, since no controlled randomized scientific study can be done where you assign a specific behaviour to random users. It's kind of like the study where spanking lowers IQ, which is scientifically invalid and a valid one would be unethical and uncontrollable. 

You could always try to create a website with downvotes and purposefully piss of random users and see what happens. Then draw conclusions from your own analytics. The conclusion, I suspect, will also depend on the type of people visiting your site.

Answer (score 16):

Whatever the fix, I believe it must be community and/or moderator-driven.  Perhaps every question that is closed as a duplicate carries a reputation penalty with it.  Not sure this would have helped in your case as it appears (from your question), that you were the only one to notice it - and you can't do this based on a single vote because the ability to abuse is rampant.

I'd completely support a negation of reputation on account of duplicates (ensuring of course, that the rep meter reports the duplicate as a reason).

Duplicates are bad, and clog up the system.

Comment: "Whatever the fix, I believe it must be community and/or moderator-driven." So should I delete this y/n?

Comment: @BoltClock, maybe we can keep *one*? ;)

Comment: IMHO, this practice is worse than just posting a question that gets closed as duplicate. Not that any duplicates are good, but at worst it's laziness or insufficient search skills. What the OP describes (and I've seen a number of cases myself) looks like a very deliberate attempt to get more attention for a question by gaming the system, at the cost of other posters who play nicely.

Comment: Duplicates aren't always bad - the reason we close duplicates without deleting them is because, when they're not straight-up reposts, they can serve as signposts pointing to the original, which is useful for searchers. We really don't want to punish that.

Comment: We shouldn't punish for duplicates in general, but I think we're justified in punishing when a question is closed as a duplicate _of one of the user's other questions_.

Comment: @Jeffrey, that is the solution.  SELF duplicates should result in a loss of rep.

Comment: @Ed Bayiates: That loss of rep is quite adequately conferred in the form of downvotes on the self-duplicates. Granted, it's mostly temporary since the rep loss will be invalidated once the dupe is removed, but then we already have the question ban mechanism for incurring more permanent consequences.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: That sounds like a good and simple strategy. At least as long as they are using only one account. But BoltClock is probably on to something. It seems likely that the downvotes and closed questions would get these users well on their way to a question ban anyway, without any additional specific punishment.

Comment: @BoltClock, that's exactly the problem -- the rep loss is temporary so the only deterrent is the possibility of being question banned, which is unlikely.  I see self-duplicates quite frequently on SO.

Comment: @Ed Bayiates: Question bans happen *very* quickly, so quickly the OP won't even realize they're banned until they try to ask their next question (or next repost...).

Comment: @RetoKoradi not always; I posted a question recently (let's call it A) that was closed as duplicate of question B. However B was also closed as duplicate of C. So my pre-posting search for duplicates never found B (that doesn't find closed questions - I'm not sure how someone else found B to mark A as duplicate of B!), and my question was sufficiently different to C that it should not be considered a duplicate of C.

Comment: I don't think a loss of rep would be an effective punishment for these users. Most of the ones i've seen do this don't have any rep to lose. The rate-limiting -> question ban probably already handles this situation adequately.

Comment: -1 and flagging for duplicating answers; according to your post, you should lose a rep for this :(

Comment: @Isaiah *whooooooooosh* ;)

Answer (score 4):

Something I believe individual users can do to prevent themselves from doing this sort of thing is to offer a bounty. In my personal experience, if I asked a question that got low views or an answer that didn't help, I would offer a bounty on it (that is, if I felt I really had asked a good question). If anything, it at least brought more views to my question.

That being said, I understand what some of these users must be thinking. They've asked a question, it didn't get the attention they wanted, and now it's so old that no one is ever going to see it. First instinct might be to just ask it again.

I understand that your question asked what the community could do to flag/prevent self-duplicates, but I think it is just as important for individuals to know what their alternatives are.

Answer (score -9):

This sounds like a problem in a specific technology domain, rather than a site-wide problem. So the question is, why is it common there? Is this a specific set of users? Is there something about this technology that draws users of a particular skill level?

If it's a specific set of users, then I would just flag one of them (per user), provide an explanation of the "serial duplication" and some links, and let the mods warn/ban/wahtever-they-see-fit to the users.

If it's not a few users but is constrained to a small set of technology or problems, I don't know that we can come up with an effective solution without having some idea why this is happening in a particular area.

If it's more widespread than I realize, then I would submit that the system needs to auto-flag users with a high number of duplicates for moderator attention. This way, the community can simply continue closing duplicates as normal and will not need to worry about tracking if a user is making a lot of duplicates. I imagine it would be possible for the system to follow a chain of duplicates to determine if the user has posted multiple duplicates of the same question, which might also be worth generating a moderator notification (or if it happens more than once or something). Basically, just automate the process of detecting when this happens, then let people examine the situation and make a determination if anything needs to be done.

Comment: I've seen it a lot on StackOverflow when users ask a question, don't get exactly what they want (e.g., the solution to their homework), so they repost the same question the next day or so.