# Prevent duplicate edit suggestions

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Do we need to have some mechanism in place for preventing duplicate edit suggestions, so users unhappy with the result of their first edit review, don't try to submit the same thing?

To complicate the matter, what about anonymous users?

Here's a [review from this morning by an anonymous user that was rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5258217)

Here's [the same edit suggestion, 11 minutes later, by an anonymous user](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5258354)

I would bet my left shoe that they are coming from the same IP address.

Comment: The reviewers of that second suggested edit, along with those in the first edit that approved it, look like they could use a break from reviewing.

Comment: To your suggestion, if we had a reasonably effective review system that would actually reject bad edits time after time, this really wouldn't be necessary.  People would just get themselves edit banned trying over and over.  In reality, we don't have an effective review system, so this suggestion has some real merit.  Of course, the main problem here is that the submitter can just make a tiny little tweak to make the suggestions not identical and all of a sudden you don't know what to do.  What if the small change was the reason for the rejection and it's not a good edit?

Comment: So now you'll get suggested edits that do whatever they did before plus s/problem/issue/ to be distinct.  It's a bit like the [self-duplicates problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262929/3614835) -- filtering out more than exact duplicates is hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a soft solution in place that just kicked in based on IP address.

If you look at the review suggestions now, [a warning is displayed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216399/209031):

> Our system has identified this edit as possible spam; please review carefully

[image: screenshot]

The next time an edit is proposed by someone within that network, it might be reviewed more closely.  This is probably a cleaner than something that targets exact duplicates, which has it's own share of issues, as Jeffrey pointed out.

Comment: I am not sure how well that works though, I just rejected [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5263708) then later I got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5263794) which I also rejected but I noticed it was incredibly similar so I investigated and also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5263659). Since the last attempted edit was approved I rolled it back but this user seems very persistent in getting his edit through and on the THIRD suggested edit it was (probably robo) approved.