# Exact duplicate question with no answers

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27393284/copy-paste-cut-buttons-are-not-visible-how-to-change-their-color) has an exact [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27058289/android-customize-and-change-color-of-contextual-menus-item-that-pops-up-for-te), but with a bounty offered by the duplicator. Yes, the same user asked the duplicated question.

I can't flag it as duplicated due to there are no answers on the first question.

I am just curious, how do I handle this? IMHO, these kind of practices are pure crap, and it just added another unnecessary question.

Comment: See also [Prevent/punish self-duplicates](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262929/prevent-punish-self-duplicates)

Comment: Is posting a "see also" link on this question the perfect example of irony?

Comment: @DerekTomes Only if the OP asked the other question

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277950/is-a-question-a-duplicate-if-the-duplicate-has-no-answers

Answer (score 23):

The [initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27058289/android-customize-and-change-color-of-contextual-menus-item-that-pops-up-for-te) has the bounty, but the [new duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27393284/copy-paste-cut-buttons-are-not-visible-how-to-change-their-color) is written better and has more information.

I would open a moderator flag requesting that the bounty be refunded and the initial question deleted.

Comment: What is wrong with editing the original to match the updated question and remove the new one without the bounty?  I'm sure there's a reason, as I type this, I get the feeling, "these guys probably will downvote this comment".   If it's the same User, that is.

Comment: @PJRosenburg The main reason is that most reviewers would consider an edit like that invalid. Either way, you need to get a moderator involved, unless you have >20k rep, then you could delete one of the questions if it's been downvoted.

Comment: (Also, you can't downvote comments.)

Comment: @AaronBrager more's the pity...