# What is the strategy to handle users who repost their questions if previous one is unanswered

Tags: discussion, questions

I have noticed a trend among some users regarding reposting their old questions [with unaccepted answers] within a short span of time. This puts their questions under the 'Newest' section and that might increase the probability of garnering a larger audience repeatedly. However, it definitely decreases the quality of this platform as it increase the number of 'dead' questions. I have even noticed some users reposting their questions after deleting their previous one (hence, cannot mark as duplicate).

What is the strategy for handling this behavior? Should these be flagged (doesn't really fit in any category currently)? Should I tell the user that I recognise the post and that they should edit and answer queries on their previous post? Or, is this something acceptable and be left alone?

Comment: If the question doesn't meet the policies, just downvote and flag for closure as usual.

Comment: No this is not acceptable. I would follow panta's suggestion. And i would tell the user in a comment as well

Comment: Downvote, vote to close as duplicate, watch as they get autobanned.

Comment: [It's always happened](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262929/prevent-punish-self-duplicates) and there's not much to do but vote/flag to close and move on.

Comment: I'd call it clever use of site mechanics. Isn't worth putting much mind to it unless it becomes a wide-spread problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If a user is posting a question multiple times you should flag the question as a duplicate of the original question. Also from what it sounds like these questions should be marked as duplicates anyways because the other questions has answers.

If you notice a user doing this a lot you can also raise a custom flag to inform a moderator of the issue and they can contact the user in question.

If the user is deleting old questions so they can get around the duplicate flags then the only option is to flag for moderator attention. It is possible that the deleted questions will get them a question ban but that may not be fast enough to stop their actions.

Comment: But, some users delete their old questions too hence, other users might not be aware that it is a repost. Isn't this exploiting of a feature of this platform

Comment: @Shaishav updated my answer

Comment: Yeah, that sounds about right.

Comment: <broken-record>This would be much less of a problem if high-rep users could see deleted questions and answers on a user profile.</broken-record>