# How should a user without moderation privileges deal with self-duplicates?

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions

In the last 4 or 5 days, I've come across three instances of different users who ask the same respective question twice or more.

[Plot Empirical autocorrelation in one plot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74266895/plot-empirical-autocorrelation-in-one-plot-in-r)

[Can I set the data argument of lavaan() equal to a variable of a data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74330295/can-i-set-the-data-argument-of-lavaan-equal-to-a-variable-of-a-data)

[Problem with the coordinate system in R in a raster file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74328774/problem-with-the-coordinate-system-in-r-in-a-raster-file)

These are all under the [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) tag. I don't visit Stack Overflow that much but if I can find these, it makes me wonder how many times this actually happens. Maybe it's just been my luck to find these odd occurrences. lol. I don't check any of the other tags, so I don't know how this tag compares to others either. But that's not the point of my question.

I found this [meta Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262929/prevent-punish-self-duplicates) and it seems to indicate that duplicate questions should be closed. When I look at the flagging options, the most relevant are

> a duplicate This question has been asked before and already has an answer

and

> in need of moderator intervention A problem not listed above that requires action by a moderator. Be specific and detailed!

While the first seems more appropriate, the questions that are considered for flagging don't have answers, so that seems to exclude the option. But requiring the use of a moderator (the second option) seems excessive. Which option is better for flagging and getting those duplicates closed?

Comment: What's wrong with flagging as duplicate? (assuming you are actually talking about the same user asking {nearly} the same questions) Or you are asking "why I can flag the same questions by the same user as duplicate even if questions do not have ansewer"?

Comment: You flag/close for duplicate. That will put in the question into the review queue so others can follow suit. If the questions are recent you can look around for a chat room that take chatter and moderation requests in the involved tag. Or you turn to a moderation specific room. SOCVR might be an option but do read their [rules in the FAQ first](https://socvr.org/faq) before posting a cv-pls there.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, my little bit of experience with moderators is that that they take things very literally. So if I flag with duplicate and there is no answer on the flagged question, flag would be rejected because the situation didn't match the flag's description exactly. However, that is action that I think of first.

Comment: @JohnPolo repeat questions by the same author can be flagged as duplicates without any of them having answers.