# What to do when I am basically forced to serially downvote a user because they keep on posting crap in my tags?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

So, there's a user (link removed, see note at the bottom) who is a member since today, has no idea how the site works and practices programming by iterative SO query. They've asked three python questions in a span of three hours, which all appeared in my stream on the SO homepage. All of them were bad (un-debugged code dump with tiny, bad problem description), more so since it's basically one huge chameleon question which just keeps on changing.
Furthermore, they've posted two non-answers to their own questions basically reading "Thanks, here's my new code, now fix this issue please".

Naturally, I've downvoted all questions and answers, and flagged the answers as NAA. I don't think this fits the definition of serial downvoting (or at least not the intention of the reversal) as I didn't target the user or stalk their profile to downvote them but came upon the posts naturally by refreshing the SO homepage. But as the reversal script probably doesn't know about this, I'm pretty sure my votes will be reversed.

Here's what I think my options are in such a situation:

- Voting on all posts seems to be discouraged by the serial voting reversal.
- I could stop downvoting once I see it's the same user that posted two other crap questions today, but that seems to be counterproductive - the fact the user already posted more crap should not be a deterrent for downvoting.
- Instead of voting myself, I can bring the posts to the attention of other users, e.g. via chat. While this solves the problem of my votes being undone by the reversal script, it feels like a bad idea as it costs more effort from me and other people, and invokes the "meta effect" of pile-on downvotes.

What should I do in such a situation? Are there options I've overlooked?

---

I removed the link to the user profile, all of their posts are now deleted anyways. And while I deliberately included the link into the original question to make sure they would be question-banned, I do think the meta effect went a bit overboard here. There are posts in more dire need of a vote than the -10 question of a user that's already banned. You only have a limited amount of votes a day, don't waste them like this!

Comment: Oh good, they're writing software to do bank transactions.

Comment: see [Fix serial downvoting reversal to not apply to users spamming site front page with bad answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199418/165773): "...cases like that would be more accurate to qualify as _content-targeted_ (ie legitimate, as opposed to abusive user-targeted, intended to be dealt with by vote reversal script). When crap-bomber unloads their answers, those looking at _slowly changing_ active tab... are literally _forced to see the new content to vote on_ - it's not like when one picks a user profile and bulldozes over their posts"

Comment: ...also related: [Ignore votes on answers deleted by moderators when checking for serial down-voting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163452/165773). That said, here is the trick to work around brainless script: just vote up one of the answers, preferably one which is most blatant NAA, guaranteed to be deleted (the one you'd feel comfortable to flag for mod deletion if LQ review somehow misses). This will give you headroom for extra downvotes (probably 5 or maybe even 7-8)

Comment: You should remove the link to the user...I think I saw a post a couple of days ago about how specific users should be left anonymous...

Comment: @BilltheLizard Well. I'm pretty sure it's a class exercise, not code that's actually running on an ATM. At least, that's what I'd like to imagine. :)

Comment: Can we find out which bank it is, so I can withdraw my money?

Comment: @DavidWallace Just don't use an ATM to do it.

Comment: nice phrase "programming by iterative SO query" did you coin that yourself? That should have a Wikipedia page if it doesn't already :)

Comment: I removed the link to the user profile, all their posts are now heavily donwvoted and deleted anyways. And the phrase "programming by iterative SO query" isn't my invention @Tom, variations of it have been floating around on meta for a long time now (probably as long as SO exists).

Comment: related: [Can there be legitimate serial downvoting?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260840/839601)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

> What should I do in such a situation?

Exactly what you did. Downvote, flag as NAA/low quality.

> Are there options I've overlooked?

No, not really.

(fyi - user has managed to get themselves q&a banned - simply by disregarding the feedback given to them. Quite a feat, in the first day of joining).

Comment: Ok, so I should simply stop worrying about the serial vote reversal? Couldn't the script in theory undo a question ban by reversing my votes?

Comment: @l4mpi - in theory. I'll just say the script has _some_ smarts to it, and in this case probably won't reverse. One way or another - the user would still be either banned or be in the rolling ban.

Comment: @Oded counter question - assuming that the script "fails" and detects a serial downvote attempt, other than reversing are there consequences for the downvoter? I hope there are - if so, should the downvoter be worried of the consequences of a single instance like this?

Comment: @SPArchaeologist - single instances shouldn't have an effect at all. This is the kinds of behavior pattern that mods get access to and where they have the discretion.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist [per my observations](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/144478/165773), a possible consequence is it becomes harder to repeat abuse - eg after script catches and reverts 4 votes down cast by user1 against user2, next time it may be triggered by a subtler attempt, like 2 votes cast by user1 against user2

Comment: The script *probably* looks *where* you were before visiting the question, it's probably far more likely to reverse votes when you were in the user's profile before downvoting the question.