# Guideline on avoiding serial downvoting on current answers

Tags: discussion

I just downvoted two answers on active posts which were terrible, and only realized afterwords that the answers were from the same user.  I know that from this [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260840/can-there-be-legitimate-serial-downvoting) that going back through old answers and downvoting is bad, but what about downvoting answers to active posts? @hakre suggested stopping after 3 downvotes.  Is that a good rule of thumb?

Note this question is different than the duplicated question - I'm asking for a limit on the number of downvotes per day to avoid be tagged as a serial downvoter.  AFAIK there is no current answer to this question.

Comment: See also: [What to do when I am basically forced to serially downvote a user because they keep on posting crap in my tags?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277544/what-to-do-when-i-am-basically-forced-to-serially-downvote-a-user-because-they-k)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood (edit: which is wrong, see comments!) the discussions about serial downvoting you shouldn't care at all. The algorithm should be smart enough to distinguish natural downvoting that happens to affect the same user more then once from directed targeted serial downvoting.

If you happen to still hit a serial downvoting reversal I would flag one of the posts where a reversal happened for moderator attention and explain the situation using a "other" flag.

Comment: Note that our response, if you flag, is that we may warn the user about low-quality content if the situation warrants it, or we may dismiss the flag as helpful without any further action. We cannot reapply the votes once they are invalidated.

Comment: you understood wrong, algorithm is _not_ smart enough, see eg [Fix serial downvoting reversal to not apply to users spamming site front page with bad answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199418/165773). FWIW I once have been hit by reversal of votes cast against 3 or 4 _deleted_ spam posts (script managed to kick in before moderators removed spammer account)

Comment: @BoltClock But could you remove the "this user has had a serial downvote reversal" flag from the user? So the script doesn't trigger quicker the next time?

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer that's unlikely. Stuff related to votes is generally _very_ sensitive, SE team is somewhat paranoid (in a good sense!) about keeping voting anonymous, so I doubt that they would let changing voting-related user flags for anyone but SE developers