# Serial (down)voting because of MSO attention ("Meta Effect")?

Tags: discussion, voting, meta, serial-voting

I often see questions here on MSO regarding steps to take because of a bad question asked, for example. However while looking at these questions, I often see these questions being downvoted a lot because of this attention on MSO.

While this might be a good thing, I also noticed (and this is based on an assumption, which is based on my observations) that a lot of the people on MSO tend to look at the user profile of this user as well, which also causes some MSO users to downvote other questions of the same user. Is this bad practise, and shouldn't this be seen as serial (down)voting?

I noticed [this question about legitimate serial (down)voting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260840/can-there-be-legitimate-serial-downvoting), which is about going through someones profile and downvoting their questions because they are basically all poorly written. The answer there suggests that it is okay to do so, as long as you do not `target` someone in general, and look at each post indifferently. But because of the case where a question gets linked here on MSO, isn't it basically serial (down)voting?

**Question linked above:**

> If you stumble across a user whose answers and questions are just terrible, is it okay to downvote and vote to close as needed, or is that crossing the line of serial downvoting?
>   It's nothing personal -- you don't even know this person -- but everything they post is just god-awful and unhelpful.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect

Comment: @Oded: I think the OP knows what the meta effect is (while not necessarily knowing what it's called), and is asking if the meta effect is a valid excuse for serial, targeted downvoting.

Comment: @Oded What BoltClock is saying ^^ (Editted title of question)

Comment: Sure - I figured that was related however, so wasn't answering.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But because of the case where a question gets linked here on MSO, isn't it basically serial (down)voting?

Multiple votes from different users on the same post does not constitute serial voting. As stated [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

> Voting fraud is when a **single user** continually votes (up or down) on **many of your posts** within a short period of time.

(Emphasis added. "Voting fraud" == "serial voting" in this context.) Now, *if* some users seeing a terrible question because of a post on MSO cross the line into going through the OP's profile and start downvoting multiple posts, that's another thing.

The [question you refer to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260840/can-there-be-legitimate-serial-downvoting) is a concern about whether when someone *happens* to run into a user who just posts terrible contents. If they start voting on that user's content is it going to be treated as serial voting by the system? My take on this based on what I've read is that if you go *through the user's profile to find their posts* and downvote them, then your votes are at risk of being considered serial voting. Maybe the serial voting detection script is more intelligent than I give it credit for but given that going through a user's profile is *exactly* what a revenge-downvoter would do, I'd avoid doing this.

There's still the case of a user who posted a lot of really terrible answers in a tag and you happen to find them while scanning the active questions for the tag, and downvote them. Is it serial voting? I my experience this won't be seen as serial downvoting. The user made their posts visible to the community just by posting them. I've had this happen not long ago in one of the tags I am active in. A user serially posted really terrible answers and I downvoted most of them. As far as I know my votes were not reversed.

Comment: Thank you for these insides, it gave me a better understanding of the process behind this.

Comment: _"Maybe the serial voting detection script is more intelligent than I give it credit for..."_ -- no, [folks at Programmers meta found out a while ago](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/3526/31260) that it is dumb enough to revert meta-induced "voting raids" (and I believe this is the right design decision): "just don't go on a down voting spree..., last time he made it into Meta three people started downvoting everything and they were caught by the serial voting script..."

Answer (score 6):

The meta-effect would work just as well, and draw a lot less complaints, if meta posts ever featured *good* posts.  But they don't, everybody likes to complain about bad ones.  Come on folks, y'all can do better, I favor reading good posts much more.

So it isn't really the meta-effect that's at fault, it is the mechanism by which we highlight SO posts.  Posts that attract views automatically draw votes, up or down.  In general something that can use improvement, I for example almost never see a good SO question featured in the "Hot Network Questions" list.  Not subscribing the newsletter, I can only ever find them back for the 10K moderator tools page, not accessible to everybody.

Lost opportunity, it makes no sense to feature questions from *other* SE sites in the SO meta.  That list there ===> should only have SO questions.  The "good" kind of meta effect.

Comment: Actually, sometimes they actually feature good ones. Like the one time I complained about a good answer by me being deleted (which highlighted the extreme risk questionmarks in answers anywhere but in comment (or code) blocks represent. I concede that such posts are quite rare occurrences though, in comparison.

Comment: Well, we can't vote on deleted posts :)