# When a user answers his own question with a slightly changed version of an other answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

Was helping a new user of SO yesterday and after some back and forth in comments and then in chat and through updates of question and answer, I noticed he really wasn't adjusting well to SO.

So after hitting the escape button before I thought him everything about everything I took a look at his other questions. Two things were very odd.

1. he was not accepting answers.
2. he was answering his own question with implemented code of answers posted by others on his question.

I commented on the question I helped him with about this and now he has accepted a lot of his questions. (score!)

A bit later I noticed he ignored my second remark (about posting the answers) and did it again.

How bad is this? Or is this actually useful? In some way it is the perfect answer to his question because it is very specific. On the other hand it will not help a lot of other people, which is the point of SO.

I already flagged the most useless of his answers and again placed a comment asking him not to do that. Or is that wrong of me?

I have already posted a link to the Tour which I hope he took.

There are examples were he ignored the better answer and posted truly bloated code and were he implemented an answer, posted it again and asks for feedback on the answer.

Comment: He didn't.  Reading the tour page grants the "Informed" badge which the user doesn't have.

Comment: @theB Forgot about that badge :)

Comment: It seems like the user thinks this is a forum, they're using their answers to their own questions to ask more questions (from what I've read). The best thing for this user would be to take the tour.

Comment: @TinyGiant Good point. Didn't think about it like that yet. There probably isn't a blocked-until-you-take-the-tour option? The only reason I asked about it here is because he does not respond to my remarks in any way. So I don't know if he understands it now.

Comment: He probably doesn't, and most likely doesn't care enough to try. All he wants is his code fixed. He will probably continue to treat the site like a forum no matter what any of us do. The most you can do is flag and vote to the best of your ability, while not paying specific attention to the user. I wouldn't suggest stalking any user, but if you do happen to notice a trend from a specific user then you can use a custom mod flag on one of their posts detailing the issue that you see.

Comment: There are a couple of possible explanations whenever you see somebody commenting "Thank you, this is really useful" to his own answer and that comment is upvoted.  None that have anything to do with normal usage of an SO account.

Comment: I have removed the examples you linked to prevent some [meta effect](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283693/serial-downvoting-because-of-mso-attention-meta-effect). Users will find the offending posts via your profile if they really want to....

Comment: @rene Thank you, I also haven't down-voted him, I believe there is grace period for bad behaviour. Just really annoying when you can't put them on the right track.

Comment: A very good explanation of @rene showing how it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Self answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) is allowed, so there is nothing stopping a user from posting their full solution to their own question.

It does require attribution if parts of the answer are blatantly copied. Leave a comment, linking to the [attribution required](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) blog and [licensing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) is a first step. If it is habit consider flagging for a moderator but make sure you explain clearly with links to examples of what is copied.

Keep in mind that it is not required to accept answers. If none of those answers really helped the OP is free to not select an answer (or up vote any answers). Vote or flag the post as you see fit but don't go on a witch hunt by visiting and voting on all their posts. That is better left for moderators.

If you find your self in a situation going back and fourth in comments, posts and chat be sure to verify the signs of [help-vampirism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem) and bail out early if you run into one.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Since I have found the link to this place, and I think OS is a nice, useful place, I see now that I have to give some answers to the complains:

1)  Funny case :). In post ([function to find all NSRanges for a string in string in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32806108/function-to-find-all-nsranges-for-a-string-in-string-in-swift/32810474?noredirect=1#comment53677043_32810474)) I see my comment with "thank you" below my post, it looks like I thank myself :). Funny, it is because it was addressed for user **Leo Dabus**, for his comment that he posted the complete solution by using NSRegularExpression, which I did not wont to use and have wrote in comment that it will be useful for others. He simply deleted his comment, in result I thank myself :)

2)  In post ([How to find all positions of one string in another string in swift2 ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32285412/how-to-find-all-positions-of-one-string-in-another-string-in-swift2)) I posted question , I have got suggestions (not code) in wich direction I have to look for and I have got answers (code) to use NSRegularExpression, which is not choice for me. I have wrote purely my code and posted as answer. For this I have got minus likely from R Menke. OK, such reaction on such post is funny complain for incorrect usage of SO :).

3)  Suggestion from R Menke were useful for me ([How to implement finding all positions of one string in another string at the time of typing the string where to search for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32890014/how-to-implement-finding-all-positions-of-one-string-in-another-string-at-the-ti)), I have wrote "thank you" many times, voted up his post and accepted his answer as answer to my question even if it was not exact. He suggested to use NSViewController and not NSWindowController. I have checked this for NSWindowController and it was working, and whole discussion at the end I see now (what I did not know before as beginner) was not about even piece of code it was about usage of standard function in Cocoa. I have posted concise answer, which in my view is useful for many beginner.

4)  I have rated and accepted as answers to my questions all good answers from my point of view, not immediately but after a while, when I could understand the value of these answers.