# New user unaccepted my answer and posted own implementation of my answer

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, unaccepted-answer

Recently I answered a question with an approach to the user's question which after some clarifying comments with the OP was accepted. My approach wasn't meant to be directly usable as there were some functions I told the OP they would need to write for it to work properly.

After a few days I see my answer is unaccepted, and they have posted their working code using a slight variation of the approach I posted. On the one hand, I understand it may be helpful for future users to see the working answer implemented, but on the other I feel I lost out on an helpful and satisfactory answer.

The OP in this case is a new user, so I wasn't sure if it was appropriate to suggest re-accepting my answer or what to say. They seem to just want to post the specific answer to help others so I don't want to discourage them.

Should I address the OP about this or just let it go?

- I am aware of [this previous question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307320/when-a-user-answers-his-own-question-with-a-slightly-changed-version-of-an-other) but the context is different

Comment: Just let it go, it would have been nice if the OP gave you an upvote since they clearly found it useful but they're not required to do this

Comment: There is no way to "address" this. Acceptance is the question asker to give, no one else can do anything about it. What they did my be poor etiquette, but there is nothing anyone can do about it.

Comment: If the OP's solution is a duplicate of your answer, I would personally flag it, as plagarism isn't welcome on SO. If, however, the answer is different enough, then I see no problem. Sometimes an answer someone gives is enough for the OP to get the real answer they need, and the prior answer just gave them a stepping stone. I would suggest that the OP at elast upvote the answer that acted as the stepping stone though. *(Note, the OP may well have upvoted you, but you won't be able to see that, due to them only have 11 reputation. You need 15 reputation to upvote visibly.)*

Comment: @Larnu Interesting! I didn't about the 15 rep requirement. My answer was more about a suitable approach and theirs was the implementation of the approach so probably would be considered different enough

Comment: There's probably a few [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) you take for granted that others can't use, @DublinDev . Such as this very (meta) site. :)

Comment: @Larnu Regarding that visibility, this essentially boils down to OP not being able to upvote. Invisible upvotes are useless after all, as are invisible downvotes.

Comment: I wouldn't say they are completely useless, @Mast, as the data is still [stored](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/339185/2029983) (and so can be found elsewhere). We can't, however, demand that a user makes sure they get 15 reputation first before they upvote. :)

Comment: @Larnu Well, that answers explains the votes are basically stored in an archive where nobody looks. How is that not useless?

Comment: I said not completely useless, I didn't say not uselss, @Mast  ;)

Comment: It happened to me yesterday and I'm disappointed. Could we propose to add a gold badge for this?