# How should I handle a lot of questions by a single OP that I feel should be closed?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I recently read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28151457/switching-streams-in-rx), I voted to close it as I feel it doesn't meet the standards of SO. The OP commented and gave the impression it had annoyed him, so I replied explaining my reasons.

What caught my eye was how the user had gotten so much rep yet still managed to ask such a poor question, so I looked through his [user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1198559/jhegedus) for some past questions. Having looked through them there seem to be a lot that I would naturally vote to close for whatever reason (a lot seem too broad). I voted on a couple but I am now hesitant to cast anymore votes as I don't want to seem like I am targeting that specific user.

Should I just continue to vote on the ones I think should be closed? Regardless of the fact they all have the same OP.

In general there seems to be something more suspicious going on. Some questions have answers with what seems to be a lot of effort put in for such a poor question ([this one for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27642230/compiling-newest-scala-language-specification-into-pdf-format)). I am a bit lost as to why this user has been able to create so many questions without any close votes being picked up? Though perhaps this is because Scala is more niche and doesn't have as many 'voting users' viewing them?

Comment: There seems to be this increasingly popular meme these days about how hostile SO has turned. Yes, a lot of the times there are bad questions (like WTF) - but I feel that we've become very "picky" and close/downvote stuff for even the smallest reason. Sorry I can't give examples at the moment, but trust me when I say there are many such cases.

Answer (score 14):

In regards to that specific user, I see nothing suspicious at all in anything I have access to here. While you may think many of their questions deserve to be closed, I see many specific programming-related questions that received very good answers. I don't think I'd close many of these, myself. There's nothing at all anomalous about any of the votes they've received.

Close votes are subjective, so what you think is worthy of closure is not necessarily what others would agree on. Again, many of these look like decent question to me.

I might not target a specific user with close votes, because that seems to me like you're starting to prejudge content based on the person who left it. I've seen that be used vindictively, and we have had to warn people about targeting folks like this. If there are a few obviously bad things to act on, OK, but I might not work your way through their history with close votes.

I can't find them right now, but we had a general set of guidelines here about going back through someone's question history and downvoting. I'd apply the same sort of thinking to this as with downvotes like that.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260840/can-there-be-legitimate-serial-downvoting

Comment: OK, I am keen to try and learn something here. Like I said, I am starting to doubt my standards for judging. Let's take [this question for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28021313/hot-vs-cold-observables-explained-in-rxscala-using-scala-code-examples), could you explain why this isn't "too broad"?

Comment: @musefan It's not too broad because one can explain the differencebetween those two concepts (in a sufficiently complete and quality answer) in a few paragraphs or less.

Comment: @musefan - I may be more forgiving, but the question is fundamentally "What is the difference between hot and cold observables in Scala?" That seems concrete and objectively answerable. Rather than voting to close, I've reworded the question in a way that I think brings out the core issue. Take a look at that and see if it makes more sense now. It may just be rougher English or poor phrasing that are the real problems here.

Comment: The example I mentioned does indeed have a answer with only a couple of paragraphs, but should that be used to judge the validity of the question? Also, who gets to decide if that answer is detailed enough? I expect somebody could easily provide an answer 3 or 4 times as long. Then does the question become too broad? Would you have a different view if the question didn't already have an answer? [What about this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27642230/compiling-newest-scala-language-specification-into-pdf-format), it has a fantastic answer but that doesn't change the question quality

Comment: @musefan You can always provide an answer that's *way* to long to *any* question, no matter how narrow.  What's important is that its possible to provide a quality answer in a reasonable scope.  If it's *impossible* to provide a quality answer to the question in a reasonable scope, then the question is Too Broad.  As to who decides whether the answer is detailed enough, or a complete answer, the voters (both close voters and regular post voters) do.  Even without that answer, I wouldn't expect an answer to need more than a few paragraphs to answer it, and so wouldn't close it as Too Broad.

Comment: @Servy: OK, I think I will try and be a bit more reserved with my "too broad" votes in the future. I do have a habit of using that one for questions that show no effort. For example, "How can I update a textbox when a button is clicked?". That can be answered in a couple of paragraphs, but I am no the only one who would vote to close that as too broad. Maybe I just miss the old close reason for when OPs showed no effort, perhaps I should just try and forget about voting on questions I feel show no effort as it often gets confusing on which is the correct action to take

Comment: @musefan There never has been a close reason for the OP not providing enough effort.  There were close reasons that were *mistakenly* interpreted as meaning the OP didn't provide enough effort and had to be removed because people were *abusing* them to close questions purely for not demonstrating what they felt was enough effort.  That was a shame, because the real close reasons were actually useful to have, when they weren't being abused.

Comment: @Servy: Ah yes, I remember now. I seem to recall we had 2 reasons that were very similar and it was often difficult to know where to draw the line. I am sure one of them was something like "asking for too much", which is understandably misread as "hasn't put enough effort in"

Comment: @musefan "too broad" isn't the same as "lacking in detail".  The question "how do I make sure I'm writing good code all the time" is too broad; the question "what's wrong with my code, it doesn't work" is lacking in detail.

Comment: @musefan: Broadness has nothing to do with the potential length of an answer. Some concepts just requires a lot of writing to explain. Instead, broadness refers to the fact that the question requires the explanation of too many concepts in order to answer. Both the examples you've linked to seeks clarification on one or at most two related concepts.

Comment: Have to agree with this, any large number of downvotes from a single source to a single target is likely to get picked up as suspicious activity, possibly reversed, and possibly putting yourself under the ever-watchful eye of a moderator :-) I'd find the two worst and just vote on those. Not _every_ single person is required to clean up _every_ single bad post, it's enough that you clean up _some._