# How do I encourage better quality questions, and discourage poor quality?

Tags: discussion, questions, new-users

A relatively new user has stumbled upon my area of interest, asking many low quality (vague) questions that show a lack of prior research. This user has 44 asked questions in 37 days, and answered none.

I've interacted with them on a number of questions, and they have a pattern of asking very broad questions, then asking new related questions when they get stumped based on feedback from other users.

Also, they've somehow managed to gain 87 reputation, apparently from having the occasional question that ends up having useful answers. It's a bit of a paradox. I think if they have a good question, they deserve due credit, but there's hardly any down votes on their poorer questions. Probably because there are just so many that hardly anyone is reading them.

I don't want to be too harsh with them, because there does seem to be a language barrier, and they do seem to be learning a little bit, but they're leaving a lot of useless questions in their wake. Is this considered ok? How many questions is too many? Should I flag questions that they are clearly moved on from and don't need an answer to anymore? If so, which flag would be appropriate?

Comment: "and answered none." If the user is as bad as you think he/she is, don't encourage them to answer any questions.

Comment: I don't like to reserve judgement about someone's overall competence as a programmer by the fact that they asked a lot of vague questions. I just feel that it would be a kind of trade-off in time and energy if someone came and asked a bunch of questions in an area they are unfamiliar with, but also took time to answer some questions in an area where they have experience. It's a very broad field. I know C# and JavaScript well enough to answer questions. If I tried to write some Python, I would have more questions to ask than answer.

Comment: I typically leave a comment and a downvote, sometimes on more than one of their questions, using the shortcut codes `[faq]` and `[ask]` (they only work in comments). Something like: _Please help us help you. Be succinct and complete, show what you have done, what exact output or errors you are getting and what the expected output is. Without that, it is a guessing game and we won't be able to help you. Take a minute to read the [faq] and [ask], it'll safe you and us countless of hours, a minute well spent._

Comment: Why is your first paragraph singular and the rest plural?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they

Comment: I do not think I'm somebody to much permissive about teaching. I learnt to teach to army men at a military school... you pointed the langage barrier, you should also take in count that you may don't know the age. For some people (even adults) it can be pretty hard to formulate a question about something they almost don't understand. You are free to comment, downvote or ignore questions, which are enough to "encourage better quality question". At some point of your question you show that you are worried about the fact they gain reputation, I can't help myself to think that's what annoys you...

Comment: Truthfully, I can't say as I am so objective as not to be slightly annoyed that someone can put out a bunch of random low quality questions and gain rep almost as fast as I did by putting out high quality answers. I try to be as objective as possible, but I'm only human. I have changed my perspective a little bit since I asked the question and read others' opinions, though.

Comment: @Balrog30 actualy your question makes me think that it would be valuable to SO to separate two kind of questions. The ones like when a `;` is missing somewhere in the code. Such question could be kept I don't know how much, but let say 3 months. And other questions like "how to convert an integer to string" wich can be (re)useful to many people. The difference between these two sort of question could be made by upvoting. If a question has more than zero (up)vote, the question is kept for the next trhee months. By that way, we could even erase questions with obsoletes answer. Just my thought...

Comment: @bob-theunholymetalmachine - The ones with a missing `;` can be closed as off topic because they're typos. Used to be called "too localized". Basically the answer `you're missing a ; on line 10` is only ever going to be useful to the one person that asked it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Unless the questions are *very* low quality or spam, you don't want to flag them.  You would instead vote them down at your own discretion.

If the questions are genuinely too broad, then you would flag to close appropriately.  But, if they're borderline and you just don't agree with them, then the discretion of voting is left to you.

> How many questions is too many?

[50 per month is the limit.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89217/175248)  Outside of that, there's really no limit on what any one person can ask.

> Should I flag questions that they are clearly moved on from and don't need an answer to anymore?

Who's to say that a question that they asked doesn't get a phenomenal answer several months down the road?  [There's even a badge for it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/837/revival) - [two of 'em, actually.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about the 50 question limit, but that seems reasonable.  High enough that 99% of users will never hit it, but low enough to keep insanity at bay. One of the problems with this situation is that they ask a question with two problems.  They get and answer to one and then ask another question for the other problem.  I think they have 4 questions now trying to achieve the same goal.

Comment: Those scenarios are different.  You should look to guide the person to break them up into separate questions instead.  The real tricky part comes when someone decides to answer all of the questions posed - no matter how disparate - if there is genuinely two questions here.  See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions .

Comment: Thank you, this has been genuinely helpful.  I like the suggestion on the question about chameleon posts to still answer questions, but take more and more time between to give them some time to think about how to solve the problem themselves.  This could work - as long as they don't use the time between to ask more questions.

Answer (score 51):

Downvote.

First and foremost, if you see a poor-quality, poorly-researched question... Downvote it. Regardless of whether the author has written 4 of them or 400 of them; vote on each question according to its own merits.

Then, if you have the time and inclination, leave a comment suggesting methods for improvement. You don't need to get into a conversation; a few hints and perhaps a link to the help center will suffice (and if they don't, then probably nothing will).

But first, downvote. This sends a signal to the author, to other readers, and to the system itself that there is a problem with the post. All may react to help, even if you do *nothing* else.

And of course, when you see *good* questions, upvote them - again, regardless of who wrote them. Those signals are important too...

Comment: "Regardless of whether the author has written 4 of them or 400 of them; vote on each question according to its own merits." This. Do not worry that you're finding yourself downvoting yet another low-quality question by the same user. As long as you're not actively looking to downvote something *by that user*, you're not targeting them, and *it's not your fault they are repeatedly shoving poor questions down your throat*.

Comment: (unless nobody's voting on them, in which case, yeah the non-voters are probably part of the problem)

Comment: I'll downvote a question, wake up the next morning to find three more, and then get one later in the day.  They're all bad, but now I've downvoted 5 of the same user's questions in < 24 hours.  Never been reversed yet, but it's always a worry at the back of my mind.

Comment: See BoltClock's comment, @davidism

Comment: Contrary to @BoltClock what you oughtn't do is find a user whose questions are really that bad ("unclear, not useful") and then look at the user's profile, find a dozen other bad, dead questions, and downvote them. No matter how correct the actions, the mysterious serial downvote mechanism will kick in, reverse your votes, and send you a vaguely threatening note saying "don't do that or else...". I forget what the "or else..." punishment entailed.

Comment: @msw: I don't think the mechanism sends any messages on its own. The reason it reverses the votes regardless of intent is because it *can't* discern your intentions and is choosing to err on the side of caution. It's the job of a moderator to make a judgement call on that. Related post: [Can there be legitimate serial downvoting?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260840/can-there-be-legitimate-serial-downvoting)

Comment: Just stressing on the "plus side" of "upvote", then a good question in particular should derserve such a comment, even if the comment really does not "add anything to the question itself". But it arguably does for the express example of "this is what you all should be doing". Possibly the same for "answers" ( much like here ). As something explicit is not as meaningless as "+1 good answer"

Comment: I agree that up and down votes are the built-in way to give positive and negative reinforcement.  I do however feel that it is so very non-specific. For this example the negative behavior is asking lots of questions without doing any independent research.  Down votes alone do nothing to indicate to the new user that they are causing frustration for the very people who can and do help them. I feel a comment is necessary in this situation, but tact is needed so as not to give the impression of general negativity.

Comment: If you have the skill and drive to comment constructively, then by all means do so, @Balrog30 - but if you can't, then don't let this keep you from voting.

Comment: I have also been downvoting relentlessly on bad questions, but questions which barely pass the look OK threshold for an average person but are simply terrible questions in the eye of an expert get upvote from passerby when they see the question downvoted. Close vote also doesn't work, for the same reason.

Comment: @Balrog30 A big red negative number when they log in has some feedback.  Clicking and seeing what questions where downvoted could produce more.  Being told by the system they have been banned temporarily from asking questions because their questions have been poorly received is more feedback.

Comment: @nhahtdh if you want second-order downvotes (other people to agree), you usually will have to comment about what is wrong with the question.

Answer (score 9):

**Lead by example**

You already signal *they do seem to be learning a little bit*, so it looks like they want to learn.

Edit their questions if you can make them better, keep writing comments for clarification, and keep guiding them in the comments. You can still keep it courteous and friendly while doing what needs to be done:

*Sorry, I voted to close as 'too broad' because you are actually asking 3 questions in one (quote1, quote2, quote3). You can [edit] your text and reduce it to one clear question to prevent further downvotes.*

Or because... *It shows a lack of prior research. Simply [searching this site for X](search link) gives you...*

*I have edited your question and [changed whatever]. Please do that yourself next time. Here(link) is the help.*

Etcetera...

Yes, it takes patience and effort (luckily you are not the only one hanging around), and you can never predict what the result will be.

Answer (score 1):

You see, knowledge what questions to ask is a valuable kind of knowledge. The right question contains more than a half of the answer.
So a good answer for an incorrect question could look like: "this works this way, you should be asking either this or this or that." There is a probability that later someone else will ask a similar incorrect question and find your answer, and will learn what right questions to ask instead.

In other words, a frequently asked bad question is in fact a good question. It just needs an adequate answer.

Comment: In theory, this could work, in some cases. It can be problematic when the question is too broad. There's just no way of knowing what the user does and does not know. It winds up being a two day discussion back and forth with them to get to the actual root of the problem.

Comment: There should be some typical questions, for example, the phrase "Please include the adb logcat logs" could be made a button for Android questions. One of possible situations leading to a wrong question is: P wants to do X and thinks how he could do that. P decides that to do X he needs Y and Z. So P asks: "how can I do Y and Z", probably, in two separate questions. In the best case, P explains why he needs Y. But more often he considers such stuff a commercial secret. While the answer may be: there is an environmental variable V that contains information about X (but not about Y or Z).

Answer (score -8):

You can't.
There are two Stack Owerflow sites: an imaginable one and a real one.

On the imaginable one all the above answers would certainly work and a downvote would make people write better questions and an upvote would encourage good questions. On the real site you will learn that [voting is caused only by emotions, not quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32524300/a-wrong-mysqli-statement-but-why#comment52906588_32524402). This site is driven my the community, not professionals. Your downvote will be easily reverted by a "supporting upvote" from Mother Teresa-kind. A vote from a professional has the same weight as a vote from unsuspecting passer-by. And just because professionals are scarce and enthusiasts are vast, your vote will never be of any significance.

On the imaginable site they say "vote as a too broad", but on the real site you will never get enough votes to actually close a question.

On the imaginable site they say "Stack Overflow is not a forum", but on a real one they urge you to make a forum, by writing a comment and eventually engage in a long nursing dialogue, working as a free tutor.

On the imaginable site they say that Stack Overflow is for good questions that can be help for many people, but on the real site 99% of questions are too localized pleads to find a simple typo or duplicates. This system is designed this way, and nobody wants to actually change it.

Eventually on a real site you will learn that the only plausible answer a concerned participant can get on Meta is "Move on. Just move on. We want things remain the same as they are."

Featured soundtrack: [Bob Geldof - The Great Song Of Indifference](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NoweGN8cm5g). It would make a great Hymn of Stack Overflow.

**Update.**
Judging by comments, it seems I were misunderstood.
I didn't mean you shouldn't try or even have to give up.
All I meant is you can only count on yourself. There is no system to help you in your task. [The system is designed to encourage bad content.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171172/stack-overflow-technology-makes-me-write-bad-answers) And Meta represents only imaginable Stack Overflow, no working solution for the real site can be found here.

All you can do is to talk to user and plead them. That's all.
Given number of users, I find this way inefficient, but it is up to you and I never said you shouldn't try.

Comment: I am not sure negative contributions of this kind really help - isn't your "just give up" opinion well known already?

Comment: For your main tag, at least you got the PHP room to complain. For my main tag, it's even more of a landfill without any effective way to manage.

Comment: To be fair, I see no "just give up" opinion. Just observations that may cause you to give up. But meh, this is basically an observational study and observational studies are **always** wrong.

Comment: I can see your point for sure, but I don't think Stack Overflow got to where it is by people giving up. If I actually did not have the time to help people, I wouldn't be here.  I just want to encourage new users to use the system in a way that makes good use of the volunteers that are helping them. It can be hard at times to suppress the impulse to be negative, which is why I'm here on meta looking for feedback that will lead to ways of teaching new users without them feeling like the community is overwhelmingly negative.