# How should I review a low quality question on triage?

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues, triage

I was doing some reviews and I've found this question: [Failed to start an Appium session, Error: Could not find adb. Please set the ANDROID_HOME env variable with the Android SDK root directory path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38869169/failed-to-start-an-appium-session-error-could-not-find-adb-please-set-the-and)

The question has external links to code and error screenshots. IMHO this is a really poor quality question and I'd had liked to flag it. But I don't see any low quality flag on questions (like the one for answers).

Why is that? How should I review a question like this then? Voting down is not an option in Triage, so I'm confused.

I've found this answer on meta: [How do I encourage better quality questions, and discourage poor quality?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303732/how-do-i-encourage-better-quality-questions-and-discourage-poor-quality)
which encourages to vote to close the question. The problem is that I don't have enough reputation to do that.

Can anyone explain? Thank you.

Comment: Either flag it or select "requires edit", posts that require edit will later go to the low quality posts queue where they can be downvoted, deleted etc.. by users with +2K rep

Comment: If you don't think it can be edited into shape by someone other than the OP and you think it isn't OK in its current form then mark it as unsalvageable.

Comment: Ok, I've figured out myself that I should mark it as unsalvageable. But what reason should I choose for the flag?

Comment: "unsalvageable" is not really what you think it is. OP can still edit his question and make it better

Comment: In a case like this needs MCVE works as well.  <rant>Why do people post code as a image?  It is a lot easier to copy and paste it into the question then taking a screen shot.</rant>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Images of code and error messages are not very useful since they won't be indexed by search engines and you can't (easily) copy them to your favourite editor, where you can search and replace, compile, debug and so on. The images should certainly be replaced by real text, preferably copy/pasted directly from the OP's editor.

So what are your choices?

- ### Look OK

  No, certainly not, as explained above.
- ### Requires Editing

  This will send the post to the Help & Improvement queue, where other reviewers can attempt to improve the post, or send it back to the Triage queue for re-reviewing. It is unreasonable to expect the H&I reviewers to type in the code and errors from the images, so **this is not an option**.

  Yes, yes, I know the help text for the Requires Editing choice says *"...edits by **the author** or others..."*, but this is wrong. **R-O-N-G, WRONG**. The post will never be bounced back to the OP through this choice. This problem has been pointed out several times since the inception of the Triage queue, but it's still there. Go figure.
- ### Unsalvageable

  This will send the post to the Close Vote queue (unless it is spam or rude), where those reviewers can choose to put the question on hold so that no further answers can be posted. Once the OP has edited the post into shape, it will enter the Reopen queue, where the post has a chance to get reopened so that answers may be posted again. This way we end up with a question/answers-combo that is (hopefully) useful for future visitors.

  **This is the appropriate choice in this situation.** You would typically flag/close questions with this kind of problem as

  ***should be closed...** → **off-topic because...** → **Questions seeking debugging help...***

  If you want to be extra helpful, you can leave a comment to the OP to copy/paste the contents of the images as text instead.
- ### Skip

  Well, if you're still in doubt, this is *always* a valid option.

Answer (score -2):

That question needs work... it needs a lot of work.

It looks like the code is actually available, although in the form of a picture. So it can be improved by others. It also seems that with that information, it becomes answerable. So it <kbd>Requires Editing</kbd>. That option will send it to the Help & Improvement queue, where someone can edit the code into the question properly<sup>1</sup>.

Personally, I would also leave a comment for the OP, telling them to post the text of their code, not a screenshot. The OP seems to have no experience with SO (no posts, no points, no badges). A little explanation about how the site works can go a long way.

<sup>1</sup><sub>*Although in practice, it's more likely that some lazy badge-farmer will just inline the images and pat themselves on the back for having done nothing useful at all.*</sub>

Comment: `some lazy badge-farmer will just inline the images` This isn't necessarily caused by badge farming. [What if the OP adds another screenshot while you're painstakingly converting a screenshot to text by hand?](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=31963725#31963725)

Comment: @dorukayhan That can happen - and it's extremely annoying when all your editing work is undone because the OP is adding more cr*p. I've had that too, a few times. But in the H&I queue, that's probably not what happens. Over there, chances are that somebody will just inline the images instead of turning them into text properly. Sorry, I've seen too many editors over there make the absolute minimal edit just to get rep & badges, without helping in the least.