# Was I serial upvoted?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

I recently logged on to Stack Overflow to find +70 rep in my account tab:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1680836/war10ck?tab=reputation

While I appreciate the upvotes and the reputation gained from said upvotes, I'm concerned I may have been serial upvoted as the time between the upvotes is much shorter than what's usually gained by random users finding something useful and choosing to upvote. I'm a devoted fan of Stack Overflow and don't want to be flagged for inappropriate behavior so I wanted to know what the best course of action is for this? If it involves reversing the votes and losing the +70 rep, I'm fine with that. I'd just prefer not to have my account locked and marked by the serial voting script for having abusive or malicious behavior.

Comment: Does it matter? If it's serial it'll be reversed anyway... If you didn't do anything wrong... *chill*

Comment: @JustDoIt I figured it would be. My question is will my account be flagged as part of the problem? I'm not familiar with how the reverse script executes and what penalties (if any) are incurred.

Comment: As far as I know, a user *victim* of serial DV or UV doesn't get penalized

Comment: If you haven't done anything wrong there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: @War10ck - There are no automated penalties. Warnings, suspensions, etc. are all handed out manually by humans, and we only step in for the most obvious and excessive abuses. A handful of upvotes going between people who don't have anything in common isn't anything to worry about.

Comment: What would happen in this scenario: I find a great answer on one of the posted questions, and I "visit" that user to see which other great answers did he posted. 5 of them I find very useful and I upvote them. Is this considered serial voting, and will my votes be reversed?

Comment: We can all drop some offsetting downvotes if that would make you more comfortable...

Comment: This is very similar to "I liked an answers of that user that much that I thought he deserves more than 10 points from me so I should start voting on other answers of him", but not the same

Comment: @Cristik: your scenario is basically the same as "I found a bad answer on one question, and then specifically searched that user's answers, found other bad answers and down-voted them as well." And the answer to both is: don't do that. It may or may not be construed as "serial voting" (depending on the specifics), but regardless it's a form of targeting a specific user, which is considered harmful and unwanted behavior. This is whether you are voting up or down.

Comment: I had a case once that should have been (and was) classified as "serially upvoted" that I can confirm. It was simply reversed and nothing other than that happened.

Comment: Might be some well wisher of yours.. ;)

Comment: Sounds like you have a secret admirer!

Comment: @JustinPavatte Yeah, and just in time for Valentine's Day!.... 
...and 70 kinda looks like X0 .....

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If you have been serially upvoted, it will likely be reversed within 48 hours. If you haven't done anything wrong (it isn't a sockpuppet of yours that's doing the voting,) you shouldn't get penalized. If you do get penalized and feel that it was done in error, you can use the contact us link to get more information and possibly get the situation resolved.

I would just ignore it and enjoy the 70 additional points for the day.

Comment: 48 hours? I thought it is 24.

Comment: Probably is, I wasn't sure so I said 48 to cover both cases.

Comment: How does the site engine decide, whether it's serial or not? If someone does serial-upvotes but for the questions/answers of different people, is that still reversed?

Comment: Serial (up|down) voting is of one person. Going through a bunch of different questions and upvoting the good ones is what you're _supposed_ to be doing :)

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt should we know the exact details about how the site engine decides those things? I mean, if we know how it reacts, then people also know how to avoid it as well.

Comment: @g00glen00b Good point! Though, I asked because what I want is to give upvotes properly - indeed avoid, but in a good manner, if it can be said.

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt the exact algorithm is intentionally not disclosed to prevent people from doing just enough to avoid detection.  It has been said numerous times though if you vote "correctly" (that is read the post and vote on it based on the merits of that post), you shouldn't have anything to worry about.

Comment: When i was serial upvoted it took about a month for it to be reversed.

Answer (score 47):

As you mentioned, the timestamps of all seven votes are within seven minutes of each other, and the timestamps almost perfectly correspond to the the order of [your answers sorted by votes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A1680836).

```
Time Rank Answer
21:48   1 Javascript, setTimeout loops?
21:49   2 Push JSON Objects to array in localStorage
21:50   8 sort object then subsort further - javascript
21:54  15 How can I make a similar shape to a parallelogram in css?
21:55  14 Uncaught TypeError: Object has no method 'on'
21:55  17 Javascript error: 'undefined is not a function' when trying to remove...
```

I suspect a real user stumbled onto your profile page, sorted your answers by votes descending, reviewed several of your good answers and upvoted seven of them.

Comment: See e.g. [Can there be legitimate serial downvoting?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260840). Note that it really doesn't matter whether you are voting up or down; the problem is the serial voting. The basic answer is a strong "no".

Comment: @PeterDuniho I see your point. I removed my opinion and let the facts stand.

Comment: Wish someone would do that to me... *(commence the river of down-votes)*

Comment: Found this answer after searching on meta due to receiving a couple of upvotes within a few seconds of each other which I suspect were the result of a "thanks" for retracting a downvote and changing it to an upvote (after the author made an edit). I _think_ I should just ignore it, but somehow it doesn't sit right that that person probably viewed my profile and upvoted my questions without really reading them...

Answer (score 9):

This post pretty much says it all:

[What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Quote:

> What if I think I'm the victim of voting fraud?
>   If the voting fraud is in the progress of happening or just happened recently, don't worry about it. You should wait at least 24 hours after noticing before becoming concerned. The system should detect it and reverse it for you. Please do not try to get help on this issue on meta or by flagging for a moderator. All they will do is tell you to wait for the voting fraud script to run (they won't run it for you just this once).
>
> If the 24 hours has already passed and the suspicious votes have not been reversed, you can then flag one of your posts and explain what happened so a moderator can look into it. It is generally preferred that you avoid asking about them on a site's Meta since details of the investigation cannot be divulged and you won't actually get any information that will be useful to other members of the community.