# What to do when a user with high rep keeps posting bad questions and answers?

Tags: discussion, flags, post-ban

There's a user in one of the tags I subscribe to that keeps posting very bad questions and answers. The user has >30k rep, from popular questions posted in 2009. Some of the newer questions might not be the absolute worst I've seen, but they are in such great numbers and the user doesn't want to improve.

As an example, within the last 10 days the user has posted 7 questions, with a combined score of -15, and all but one is downvoted. The same user self-answers his own questions with horrible answers ("Use this program instead") and marks it Community Wiki to avoid the negative rep from downvotes.

Now, the answer is "Flag for moderator attention" right? Well:

> Please have a look at the questions (and answers) of this user, and consider banning him/her. It's really quite bad... – Stewie Griffin Oct 10 at 11:16   helpful
>
> Can this user please get a question ban? 27/30 last questions have a score of <=0, 16/30 have a score of <=-1. – Stewie Griffin Aug 5 at 13:15   helpful

Note that both those flags are marked helpful, but nothing has changed. I know for a fact that several others have flagged the same user for moderator attention, but nothing has changed.

> @StewieGriffin my flag is still pending, day 10 and counting

I was [optimistic once](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261062/2338750), when flagging a ~10k user resulted in a 1 year ban. For some reason, this doesn't happen here.

---

So, what to do?

Comment: down vote and move on?

Comment: It's not Javascript or C# where questions drown. It's a tag with not that much activity, so it's actually quite annoying that the questions and answers keep coming in. There are only 6 users with a score of 30 or higher in that tag the last 30 days.

Comment: Maybe you should ask: if the few posts that generated all the rep for this user is left-out in the question ban algorithm, would they be question banned?

Comment: @rene, there are much more than a few. He has 12 questions with a score >100, 30 questions with a score >= 50, and a total of more than 800 questions. He has more than 300 questions with <= 0, and about 50 with negative score. But it's the newer stuff that's bad, not everything. I agree, and I think if it was only the newer stuff he'd get banned. But he keeps getting rep every day from the old ones.

Comment: A mod does not have an enormous number of good ways to get somebody to either stop or spend more time on his posts.  You'll have to assume that the mod is engaged in a private email conversation with the user, passing on your concerns.  Very private, he won't tell you.  That needs to happen at least several times before he can reasonably apply the nuclear option.  So give it a week or two and if you see no improvement then flag again.  Repeat as necessary.

Comment: Historically, when the flag system was introduced, Jeff Atwood explicitly said flagging users with consistently bad track records is within the scope of  how the system is meant to work

Comment: There's a suspension reason meant for this kind of issue: low quality content. I've seen it once or twice.

Comment: May it be that the person using the account has changed recently? I mean: if until X months ago he wasn't posting crap and now suddenly he does, maybe it means that he stopped using SO and gave the account to his brother/friend/whatever...

Comment: @Bakuriu yeah it may possible , but the issue is there suppose to be something there, to prevent these things to happen , like if a higher repo account found with these things then it could influence the other new members in a negative way and i have seen some new guys doing it too

Comment: down voting not gonna make much sense in this case , it would be like stealing a coin from  rich donald duck's huge safe plus there always will be some up-votes influenced by the high repo to balance the down-votes

Comment: Downvote, and take comfort in knowing that if the user really is that terrible at asking questions, you won't be the only one we see with a large number of downvotes against them when investigating allegations of "revenge downvoting"...

Comment: @Pekka 웃: That is still true today. That's why the flags were marked helpful.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248388/highly-upvoted-old-posts-can-more-or-less-inoculate-you-from-post-bans

Comment: Possibly you might ask yourself if a person with good rep is asking "bad" questions, the problem might not be the question?

Comment: Never noticed that when Stewie holds his monologues, the adults never hear him?

Comment: @CharlieMartin Yes, but I'm quite sure that's not the case here. In the tag I'm talking about he has less than 30 questions with a positive score (most are old), and 23 have a negative score, out of a total of more than a 100. I have about 800 points in that tag. Not much compared to you, but still enough to recognize bad content in a low traffic tag. Users with the same rep as you and a score of several thousands tag points are annoyed too.

Comment: @CharlieMartin for the record, many of the "good" ones, are similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11497376/2338750). We need those questions, and they should probably be up voted too if it's the first time they're asked. But, it's definitely not a great question and should not make a user immune to question bans.

Comment: @StewieGriffin It's tough to make a general rule out of one anecdote. It really does seem to me that -- at least as a heuristic -- we ought to assume that a "bad question" is a good question badly written. This all goes with my cranky-old-man feeling that moderation has become a little like a homeowners association enforcing increasingly arcane rues.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is a tricky situation for moderators to deal with, and it doesn't happen often. Almost all persistent bad askers are caught by measures like the question ban. Users who start out well and go bad, or who started asking questions before the ban existed (and happened to shotgun enough of them to accrue random votes) are few and far between.

I know the exact user you're talking about, because I handled your flag on them. Just because you don't see us immediately suspending a user in response to your flags doesn't mean we aren't doing something.

You had flagged a 20k+ user, and with users with that kind of history and volume of contributions, we tend to warn first on indications of problematic behavior. Moderators have no control over the question ban, so the only tool we have to stop someone from asking more questions is account suspension (or deletion). Before we use such a blunt instrument, we'd like to see if we can correct the behavior by issuing warnings and having a conversation with the user first.

We have a standard message we can use for cases like this:

> We've noticed that you've asked many questions, a large number of
>   which were not well received by other members of our community.
>
> Specifically, many of your questions were downvoted and closed because
>   they seemed to be hastily written, or of the [type that we'd prefer
>   users refrain from asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).
>   This is a troubling pattern; we'd like to make sure that you've read
>   the help that we have available for asking questions. Please take some
>   time to read *all* of the information linked below prior to asking
>   another question:
>
> - An overview of [how our system works](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)
> - A brief [guide on how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
> - A short summary of [questions we permit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
> - Help on [formatting your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)
>
> We recommend taking a look at highly upvoted questions within the tags
>   that interest you as examples of how to ask better questions. We
>   really want you to have a good experience here, and the first step to
>   that is making sure that your questions are clear, on topic and
>   provide all of the information someone would need to answer.

If they respond positively to that (which is what happened here), we give them a chance to start asking good questions again. If the problems persist, and we see little improvement, that's when we can employ an account suspension as a last resort.

Again, suspending a 20k+ user isn't something we take lightly, so this can be tricky to handle and the actions we are taking may not be visible.

Comment: I remember an account suspension reason that goes with this message, this user has been suspended for low quality content or something.

Comment: @Braiam, have a look at the image in [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260840/can-there-be-legitimate-serial-downvoting/261062#261062). It reads: _"This account is temporarily suspended because of low quality contributions. The suspension period ends on [...]"_

Comment: @StewieGriffin how I forgot there was that...

Comment: I feel like mods should have the ability to manually question-ban people.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes - Personally, I'd feel uncomfortable with having that power. We receive flags every day demanding that we lift someone's question ban, and it's easy to decline these because we have no control over this. You start introducing humans into the mix, instead of a user-independent impartial system, and it becomes a lot easier to allege that the system is crooked. It also introduces problems for how you might judge if someone has improved enough to have this manual ban lifted. As I state above, this would only be useful for very small number of people, anyway.

Comment: I know of one user that keeps posting questions without RTFM, that are duplicates multiple times over across SO. I must have closed 10 of their questions over the last couple of months. Is that something you could warn them about? They don't seem to _get it_. I downvote where appropriate but they have 8k+ reputation and gaining daily from other questions.

Answer (score -4):

Act on posts **regardless of OP's reputation**, it shouldn't really matter if OP is on the 1, 10K or 100K reputation scale.

If the post deserves a downvote, do it and explain how it should be improved, and if you can edit - go ahead and do it. Some users gain a high reputation from only several posts, so don't expect from all high-reputation users to have perfect posts. I really don't see why bad posts from high reputation users should be treated differently.

Comment: They should be treated equally... I'm asking for the same treatment, not different... I'm quite sure a low rep user would have a ban based on the last activity of this user...

Comment: While I agree with this post, I think @StewieGriffin does have a point that the users that were here from the start have asked and answered all the common questions first. So they are earning a large number of  upvotes that will not be easily offset by downvotes on their new posts if they are bad.

Comment: i get your point but let just say if that user get downvote with improvement comments even on 5-6 posts from the same guy then there will be lot of chances that he will get annoyed and worst , that user might go after that down-voter too ?

Comment: @PavneetSingh That's true, for **both** high and low reputation users. I'm trying to say that treat posts equally, regardless of OP's reputation, that's all.

Comment: yeah i know and i agree too , i had observed this behavior just showed my concerns that this can works for once or twice but not more than that plus i have also seen some beginners doing the same thing as OP has mentioned that person deliberately created problematic confusion with simple code and answered that were so simple like a keyword missing , extra code was there etc , it's tricky way to gain repo

Comment: and i agree a bad answer can have an ok answer and an ok answer can have a good one and this is a **moto of SO to promote quality which all should encourage** ,nothing else above it , i have seen few great researched and well explained answers marked as duplicate of very less constructive answers which seems like an absolute tragedy to me

Comment: @PavneetSingh we don't mark answers as duplicated, we mark _questions_ as duplicated of _questions_. Answers is never in the mix

Comment: @Braiam yeah true , but a duplicate question divert members to the linked one which reduces the importance of the good answer and search  gives priority to top voted questions usually .few times if a question go down (due to duplicate down votes ) it effects the importance of answer too