# Are we fine with iteratively asking questions to get to a coded solution?

Tags: discussion

I am following tag [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python). Over the last few days a "new contributor" asks questions about the same "goal" (choosing things from a item/price list/dict to get up to some pregiven amount) - refining his code, question by question, answer by answer.

Are we fine with "iterative" code generation via Stack Overflow Q&A?

Essentially the answers to all his questions are somewhere between "teaching" and "debugging" his code - IMHO, he would need a tutor or some basic tutorials.

I refrained from posting a comment of

> Looking at the history of the questions you raised - you seem to be iteratively coding a solution to a problem you have by using one answer to formulate the next question and so on. Are you coding something or just looking for someone to code *for* you? Maybe you could try to apply [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929251/how-to-step-through-python-code-to-help-debug-issues) to solve some of the problems yourself? Maybe the problem you are tackling is a bit too complex and you need to go back to https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/?

Because it is going to be flagged as *condescending* or *unkind* anyway.

Coding by iteratively asking solutions on Stack Overflow just rubs me the wrong way ... is it ok to do so?

Comment: You should just downvote and maybe close vote such questions and let the engine do it's work. If an OP consecutively posts VLQ or LQA they'll get banned doing so quite quickly.

Comment: First option is to close as an appropriate duplicate (especially if you have a gold tag badge), stops the rot before answers appear. Then downvote. Otherwise, if you can't close for any other good reason, the question isn't *per se* out of scope.

Comment: Judge each question independently. Is it answerable, suitable for our model, and on-topic? If so, then it's fine. The motivation of the asker is nigh-irrelevant. But questions that require a tutorial to be written in the answer box are classically "too broad".

Comment: I'm active answering questions with the [tag:d3.js] tag, which is a library for data visualisation. Every now and then there is a user that asks a question about axes, then a question about scales, then a question about SVG styles, then a question about event listeners... whoever has experience can clearly see that he/she is slowly building a dataviz question by question. Well, as the comment above says, as long as the questions are on-topic the only think we can do is watching the slow and painful progress of the poor creature.

Comment: I suppose he is learning how to code, and how to ask good questions on SO, at the same time. Albeit slowly and painfully...

Comment: Is this about …osity? How quaint. You're pretty well off in your fancy python tag over there. That being said, if it becomes more recurring and even more basic language tutoring, such a comment *would seem helpful*. (I'd strike the mid sentence though). Perhaps even as part of an answer, which portrays a few such debugging steps.

Comment: I don’t mind if they show some evidence of research. I also think I should amend my usual comment of “ask one question at a time not a list” to something like “ask one question at a time, not a list, and be sure to show the research you have done for each question to avoid closure”

Comment: My only surprise here is that this is the first time you've noticed such behaviour.

Comment: This is actually encouraged behavior. We don't want people to ask too broad questions, but rather a specific answerable question all at once. If someone gets to an entire program from doing it this way, that should be great - we've helped the world get one new programmer and one new program... maybe we also helped other people who have similar problems.

Comment: So long as the question and answer are objectively useful then SO has a net gain of knowledge which is SO's primary resource. Is there a dubiosity to the user's intent? Maybe. Does it have a negative effect on SO? Probably not.

Comment: @TylerH From how it is described in the question, Chances hare pretty high that this only adds bloat to the page and that the answers are useful only to the original poster.

Comment: I agree with earlier commenters. As a beginner it may be hard to see how your questions should fit in. They can't be to broad, but you suggest that chopping them up into smaller parts might not be the best format either. So what should they do? I understand that the goal of SO is to provide a resource that is useful for future visitors, but I think it is inherent to beginners that they have very project-specific questions. Personally I think that is fine, as long as they did their research before asking (i.e. browsing the web and SO).

Comment: @Broman How would sticking to one aspect of a program instead of asking about all aspects *add* bloat to a page? Yes, not every question is useful to many people, but it's pretty difficult to prove a negative, and say this *won't* be useful to viewers in the future. Even so, that's not an explicit reason for closing a question, last time I checked. It's only *encouraged* that questions help others, if possible.

Comment: For me, I hate when I see a user take an answer from their first question, then open a new question with some needed changes and say "Here is my code so far" (then link the answer they just received). It's deceiving because it looks like they worked on the problem themselves, when really they're just showing someone else's work.

Comment: @TylerH Well, the comments aren't suitable for long discussions. But I do believe that when someone does something like that, chances are high that the user don't search to find a solution on their own, which in turn raises the chances that the answer already exists here at SO.

Comment: Isn't this how *everybody* codes in Python?

Comment: @Broman If an answer already exists then you should just vote to close as a dupe -- problem solved.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As a power user (not diamond mod), your role is probably not to focus on the user but the quality of the posts (the exception being the same user posting the exact same question a while later because the first one was heavily downvoted, expecting to be more lucky this time).

By what you're describing, this user asks below-par questions. Downvote / vote to close and move on.

You can custom-flag a post if you want some moderator to analyse the asking pattern, but don't focus on the user profile yourself.

Comment: Note: even if all their posts deserve downvotes, one should absolutely **not** find their questions through their profile and downvote them, as this is serial voting and it will probably get reverted. Seeing their posts "in the wild" (e.g. by browsing new questions) and downvoting them (if you feel the posts deserve downvotes) shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Dukeling [Shog disagrees as long as you vote on content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260840/can-there-be-legitimate-serial-downvoting/260843#260843). And of course the serial voting reversal script doesn't care if the content you're voting on is crap.

Answer (score 8):

If the questions are all on topic and non-duplicates, this is actually a good thing - this means that we would, at the end of the iteration, have all the questions/answers available for other users.

The one thing to look out for beyond quality, is perhaps making sure that the question is in the best position to be found by subsequent users with the same issue in different contexts, possibly by judicious editing where appropriate.

Comment: This is what I took from the question.  A newbie is following the one-question-per-question rule and learning as he goes.  Isn't that the correct way to use this site.  _Ask a question - learn something - code something up - hit a wall - lather - rinse - repeat_