# My good meta answers downvoted inexplicably

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes, meta

I have these 3 answers up that have a negative score on Meta here:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381513/10892372

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381457/10892372

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381469/10892372

Now, I was completely sure these were good answers before putting them up, and even now still don't see why they should have drawn **any** downvoting at all.

Could it be because of the poor quality of some of the questions? I'm really not sure why these could have been voted down as they answered the question pretty effectively. Am I completely missing something right now or is it something in the way Meta operates?

Comment: In general on meta it usually just means disagreement with what you wrote, not that it is badly written.

Comment: @takendarkk not always, that is oversimplifying a very complex voting culture on meta.  It can be frustrating for newcomers to pick up

Comment: That's why there's the "_in general_", "_usually_", etc... That's also why it's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @takendarkk I know and "in general" and "usually" are the words I had issue with because that is not correct.

Comment: But I'm still confused even if it means disagreement.. I honestly don't care if this post gets downvoted because of how used to it I am. Here is what gets me. Someone asks why their SO rep isn't the same as their Stack Exchange. I tell them it's probably caching and they have to wait. *Inexplicably downvoted*. Someone asks why they are blocked from answering, I tell them they probably have deleted, downvoted answers and tell them what they should do until unblocked. *Inexplicably downvoted*. I'm just doing my best to help and contribute, and I'm getting destroyed by the community for it.

Comment: I disagree with that.

Comment: It seems like you are rushing to answer just for the sake of answering, without putting a lot of care on choosing the question you answer, and without putting a lot of effort in researching your answers. Don't feel bad, just try spend more time choosing what to answer, and how to answer it.

Comment: It is unusual to see someone who's been on the site for 2 months answering meta questions, since typically one waits until one is quite sure an answer is correct before answering. Stack Overflow, especially Meta Stack Overflow, is a place where correctness is prized, and guesses are not.

Comment: But "inexplicably downvoted it's not a fair characterization. Rene's answer below has good enough reasons, and other users may have had their own.

Comment: I have been around/browsing meta for close to a year now, and only I answer ever so sparsely since I doubt my own correctness at times. It takes a bit of time to get a hang of the meta culture around here.

Comment: Oh wait, what about this one though: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381516/10892372 This is mega BS.

Comment: @JerryD There were already four answers describing more or less the same as you posted (with more detail).

Comment: That last one, at best, just restates what other existing answer say. But poorly. It's easy to imagine some users thinking it was not necessary, and hence "not useful".

Comment: Are your answers actually providing additional information?  Just repeating what others have said is...not very useful at all.

Comment: Additional Reading: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272607/can-we-talk-about-the-voting-culture-here-on-meta

Comment: @Jerry, just take it easy and spend more time thinking and researching your next post. Instead of sighing, which sounds kinda dismissive, you could try to use all the feedback you are getting on this question. Good luck!

Comment: @yivi Definitely. All I can do is improve, so that's where I'll go. Thank you!

Comment: Hey, I was about to comment on the other question you just deleted, so I'll talk to you here instead. I've seen a lot of meta posts from you over the last couple of weeks. My impression is that you didn't spend enough time watching and reading to get a good handle on the many official/unofficial site rules and the conventions and culture of meta before you decided to become an active contributor, and the reception of your posts was very hit-or-miss as a result.

Comment: But I would suggest just slowing down rather than starting over. Your enthusiasm is great and you don't need to feel like you've ruined your reputation here because some of your posts haven't been well-received. You definitely seem smart enough to learn from your experiences, and I think people will respect seeing you recover from a rough start more than they would respect seeing you disappear and return as someone else. Just be patient. :-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This one https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381513 is wrong and has a down vote from me. I left a comment on the question what the OP can expect. Maybe a better duplicate exists, if not on MSO then for sure on MSE.

This one https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381457/578411 is doubtful if that is correct.

This one https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381469/578411 shouldn't have been answered, as it gets asked several times per week. We don't need a new incomplete answer every time it gets asked. A duplicate flag would have been enough. On top of that, I believe your answer blocks the [roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba).

This one https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381516/578411 adds nothing new to any of the existing answers. Therefor it is not useful which is anywhere across the SE network a reason to cast a down vote.

Comment: I see. Should I just delete these answers then if they get downvoted?

Comment: That is up to you. You asked about the down votes, I gave you feedback on that. You can now look into those answers if you feel they can be improved. If not, and you think the answer represents your view on the matter, you can leave it as is.

Comment: Alright. But I forgot this answer, the one that drove me over the line: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381516/10892372

Comment: If anything, only the second example in your question should drive you over the line as that one seems to express your opinion.

Comment: @JerryD on Meta you should prefer not deleting a downvoted answer as long as you still stand behind it. That a bunch of people disagree is not a reason to not share your viewpoint.

Comment: @JerryD I suspect you’re falling into the trap of answering, or wanting to answer, simply to answer, to participate in the site, for reputation or recognition. Not because you have strongly held views and wish to express them. On Meta, you should only answer when you feel the latter, not the former. A good litmus test is if you answer a questions know it’s a dupe or very likely a dupe, or that if you didn’t answer, someone would come along and give substantially the same answer as you would. In those cases, you don’t feel strongly that the OP won’t get answer he needs, you just want to do it

Comment: @JerryD, adding to what Dan Bron said, my suggestion is taking your time to read past meta discussions to understand the site better. Sorting by votes and reading the top ones and the lowest ones is a good start. Some of them are pretty juicy in terms of drama, and in lots of them you'll find really levelheaded posts and quite informative ones. Have fun!

Comment: @brasofilo Great advice. I appreciate that you understand how I feel like many others do as well. Anything to better myself! Thanks!